# Rails RSpec use mock instead of stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've got a `lib` which deals with some external API. The details are irrelevant, everything works well:

```
module SampleApi
  extend self

  def fetch_mm_recommender(email:)
    handle_response(client.get("#{Sample.test_uri}/api/v1/mm_recommender", email: email))
  end

  private

  def handle_response(response)
    return parse_body(response) if response.success?

    Rails.logger.error "Request failed with code: #{response.status}, message: #{response.reason_phrase}"
    response.reason_phrase
  end

  def parse_body(response)
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end

  def client
    @client ||= HttpHelper.new(with_cert: true)
  end
end
```

I've made RSpec test for that:

```
  describe '#fetch_mm_recommender' do
    subject(:fetch_physician) { described_class.fetch_mm_recommender(email: email) }

    let(:email) { 'michael_scott@physician.com' }

    context 'when email exists in SAMPLE' do
      before do
        stub_request(:get, %r{/api/v1/mm_recommender})
          .to_return(status: 200,
                     body: sample_response,
                     headers: {})
      end

      it 'fetch user data' do
        expect(fetch_physician).to be_present
        expect(fetch_physician).to eq(JSON.parse(sample_response))
      end
    end
```

Shouldn't I use mock rather than stub? Would there be any benefit to this? if so, what should such a test look like?

[EDIT]

```
context 'when email does not exist' do
  let(:email) { 'test@test.com' }
  let(:sample_response) { 'Not found'.to_json }

  before do
    stub_request(:get, %r{/api/v1/mm_recommender})
      .to_return(status: 404,
                 body: sample_response,
                 headers: {})
    allow(Rails.logger).to receive(:error)
  end

  it 'does not retrieve data' do
    expect(fetch_physician).to eq('')
    expect(Rails.logger).to have_received(:error).with('Request failed with code: 404, message: ')
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your question? `stub_request` is not provided by RSpec - its most likely webmock and thats just the terminology it uses.

Comment: If this question is if you should be using Webmock and stubbing the actual HTTP request or just mocking your api client the answer is that it depends on what it is that you're actually testing. I don't think HTTP calls belong in helpers in the first place as your controllers/models are just as fat. You're just fooling yourself by hiding them away in another file.

Comment: @max First thing first - I always use service or helpers for such integrations because of one simple reason - it's much easier to maintain in the future. You have the integration of all endpoints of a given 3rd party API in one place. Besides it's much more readable than throwing everything into a model or, even worse, a controller. It's not even a helper but `/lib` btw. I've updated this information, although it doesn't really matter anyway.

Comment: @max Back to the question - my question is should I use stub or mock? if mock, what should this mock look like to test my `/lib` ?

Comment: Thats an extremely opinion based question and the main problem with this spec is not the use of specs or mocks but rather that it tells us absolutely nothing about the actual behavior that you are testing. I would focus on that instead. Stubs and mocks are just different tools to reach the same goal - its not important.

Comment: @max What I want to test is if the request can be made properly and whether it returns an appropriate parsed response. I've added additional test, maybe this will be clearer.